# How to display loading dialog when someone clicks a specific link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I do have an URL which opens a webpage which is very slow to load and I have no control over it.

I do want to display a loading dialog when someone clicks this URL or to block page with an overlay div when this happens.

Note: this is not the same question as the ajax related ones, this for normal URL clicks form the user, not all of them only specific ones.

```
<A href="http://veryslowload.com" onClick="...">slow load...</a>
```

I suppose that what I am looking for is what to put on the onClick.

Comment: If you don’t have any control over the webpage, how do you expect to know when to hide the loading dialog?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this :

```
$(function(){
​  $('a').click(function(){
     $('<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>').prependTo(document.body); 
  });​
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HYbV2/) (change the link to a very slow page for best effect)

But it depends on the page : if the page sends immediately some content but not the whole content, you won't have the time to see your div.

Comment: I'm surprised that just works. As you can see on my answer, I assumed the document would never be updated unless you forced a repaint.

Comment: This just adds the div before the normal link behavior is triggered. The browser doesn't remove the current page from display until it has something to display for the new one.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't remove the current page, but I thought the unload/load operation would block further updates, and it doesn't.

Comment: Be aware that on some devices / browser combo this loadingDiv might still be visible when navigating back to this page using the browser back button? Am I correct?

Comment: I works but when user click back button on browser, it still shows loading.

Answer (score 6):

If you also need an animation, it becomes a complicated matter as browsers behave very differently. Some stop all GIF animations when a new page starts loading.  Basically it comes down to something like this if you have jQuery and download the spin.js library.

**See working solution here**:

http://jsfiddle.net/7aJyP/

```
<style>
#loading {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}

#loading_anim {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    z-index:1010;
}
</style>



<div id="loading"><div id="loading_anim"></div></div>

<a href="http://pangoo.it" class="mylinkclass withanimation">link</a>



<script>

$(function () {
    $(".withanimation").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#loading").show();

        var url=$(this).attr("href");

        setTimeout(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {showSpinner();},30);
            window.location=url;
        },0);

   });
});

function showSpinner() {
    var opts = {
      lines: 15, // The number of lines to draw
      length: 3, // The length of each line
      width: 4, // The line thickness
      radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
      rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
      color: '#fff', // #rgb or #rrggbb
      speed: 2, // Rounds per second
      trail: 70, // Afterglow percentage
      shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
      hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
      className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
      zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
      top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
      left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
    };
    $('#loading_anim').each(function() {
        spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(this);
    });
}
</script>
```

If you use an animated (GIF) the animation may freeze on some browsers. I used spin.js library ( http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/ ). While GIFs get frozen the javascript animation seems to be working.

Please test with ALL browsers!

Comment: 404
That page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Although ajax would be more elegant, it's possible. You have to intercept the navigation by preventing the default event, then force an update to the UI, then change the location to the destination url. Something like this:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    // Update the UI here
    setTimeout(function() {
        // This is a trick to force a repaint
        window.location.href = url;
    },0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic, but if you want a simple solution that doesn't depend on JQuery add the following to onClick in your link:

```
<A href="http://veryslowload.com" onClick=""javascript:document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';"">slow load...</a>
```

Then somewhere on your page, have a hidden DIV that includes what you want for the loading dialog.

```
<div id="page-loader">
  <h3>Loading page...</h3>
</div>
```

and hide the DIV with CSS as follows:

```
#page-loader {                                                                                                     
  position: absolute;                                                                                              
  top: 0;                                                                                                          
  bottom: 0;                                                                                                       
  left: 0;                                                                                                         
  right: 0;                                                                                                        
  z-index: 10000;                                                                                                  
  display: none;                                                                                                   
  text-align: center;                                                                                              
  width: 100%;                                                                                                     
  padding-top: 25px;                                                                                               
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);                                                                      
}
```

Here's a JSfiddle to a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/meb69vqd/

I can't take full credit for this example. There are additional tips about this technique here: https://css-tricks.com/css-page-loader/

Comment: this solved my problem, because i am using ajaxStart fucntion, and the page will get load on this gif loading.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you'll want the loading dialog to appear immediately, then to disappear and be replaced by the new page when the new page has rendered?

Three ideas come to mind.

---

If you have control of the source page but not the target - Use a click event handler to replace the  tags' normal behavior with something like this:

1. Display the loading animation
2. Fire an AJAX request to the URL defined by the  tag's href attribute (alternately, create a hidden  with the URL as its source)
3. When the request has completed, replace the document's contents with the response.

This can get really hairy, though, since you won't lose javascript and css defined in the original page. It also won't change the URL displayed in the user's browser.

---

If you have control of the target and can make the target cacheable (even for a few seconds): You could load the page in the background via AJAX and then redirect to it. The first load will be slow, then the redirect will load the page from cache.

---

And yet another alternative: If you have control of the target page, you can define an optional parameter such that if the parameter is present, the server returns a page consisting of only the loading animation and a bit of javascript that loads the actual page.

Comment: Except that cross-domain ajax requests are generally not allowed because of browsers Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @David Oh yeah. :( Does that behavior also block the loading of cross-domain iFrames? Because that would allow pseudo-AJAX using a temporary <iframe> to still work.

Answer (score 1):

an improvement over @bfavaretto 's solution that worked for me

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e) {                                                                                   
  e.preventDefault();                                                                                              
  var url = this.href;                                                                                             
  // Update the UI here                                                                                            
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {                                                                               
    setTimeout(function() {                                                                                        
        window.location.href = url;                                                                                
    });                                                                                                            
  });                                                                                                              
});
```

the browser would inconsistently display my spinner. I tried hacking around with increasing the setTimeout's delay. The proper solution is to ask the browser when it is ready to show the spinner, then navigate away.

Comment: I know this answer is old but I have a follow up question on it, I was wondering is there a way to also detect if the User clicks on the X button on the Browser during the Page Load and accounting for that Click Event?

Answer (score 0):

initially store a spinner.gif some where in your form and keep it hidden
and also put src=""

thus there will be no src for image

but later on while making the ajax call you can set the src for the spinner image thus you page will seem to be loading

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
               $("#tempForm").ajaxForm({
               url:'url to be called',
               type:'post',
               beforeSend:function()
               {
                   alert("this is the place where you place things to happen till your page is being transfered to the given URL so i am setting the src for the spinner image here");  
                   $("#spinner image ID").attr("src","../images/spinner.gif");
               },
               success:function(e){
               alert("do whatever you want with response here");
               }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden iframe and listen for the load event. You will also need to do a manual check after about 1 sec, in case the destination has prevented x-frame content.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ijofih/1**

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).text('Loading...'); // do your UI thing here
    e.preventDefault();
    var destination = this.href;
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = destination;
    },1000);
    $('<iframe>').hide().appendTo('body').load(function() {
        window.location = destination;
    }).attr('src', destination);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into Modal boxes. You can activate a model box when the ajax request is send and on success maybe close it.
https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=modal+box