# how to show a loader gif when page is redirected on a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I am calling a javascript function on a button click and putting this
`window.location ="schedule.php?"+gstr+"&downloadall="+result;`

inside the function.I also want to show a gif through jquery but it stops when the page is redirected.

Comment: You can't show the loader using js when a page is being redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a loading gif, after the redirect takes place:

You can not do this from the page you are redirecting from!
Insert the gif in an overlay div on the page you are redirecting to, and hide it in document.ready

html:

```
<div id="loadImgWrap">
    <img src="some.gif">
</div>
```

js (with jquery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#loadImgWrap" ).hide();
});
```

---

or try this as found here: [How to display loading dialog when someone clicks a specific link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626237/how-to-display-loading-dialog-when-someone-clicks-a-specific-link)

```
$('<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>').prependTo(document.body);
```

(I haven't found a page loading slow enough to test it)

---

if you want to show a loading gif before redirecting:

the gif should be part of a hidden div.
!Before! calling `window.location..` make it visible.

Comment: why the downvote? Maybe I understood the question wrong and the user is looking for a loader on the redirected page.
When lots of stuff needs to be done before redirecting, it can appear to the user as if the site is hung up, then this can be usefull, I had a situation where it was necessary.

Comment: _but it stops when the page is redirected_. So OP can manage to display it, but not when the page is redirected.

Comment: when you redirect, a new website is displayed --> whatever you do on the "old" website obviously will not be displayed anymore. --> whatever you want to see needs to come from the new website. (if the site you are redirecting to is NOT under your control, maybe you should look into iframes to find a way around it)
or somehow state more clearly what you actually want to achieve and what stops you from doing so..

Comment: added another possible solution to the answer, but have trouble finding any page loading slow enough to actually test it.